# CoreBluetooth NotifyValue is give to nil value and descriptors in ios

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, fitbit

I have to access heart rate from Fitbit Surge Device , its give four services are with -

```
UUID - 180a (work fine for Device Information)
UUID - 180f (work fine for Battery)
UUID - 558dfa00 4fa84105 9f024eaa 93e62980
UUID - adabfb00 6e7d4601 bda2bffa a68956ba
```

I have to set `[peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:c]`, with `[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"ADABFB01-6E7D-4601-BDA2-BFFAA68956BA"]` `didUpdateNotification:` are `<CBCharacteristic: 0x17dc6bb0, UUID = ADABFB01-6E7D-4601-BDA2-BFFAA68956BA, properties = 0x12, value = (null), notifying = YES>`.
But `value` is `nil`.

Please help me or any suggestion .

Comment: @Larme give me answer ???

Comment: I don't know the answer of your issue. It's been a while since I played with CoreBluetooth, and more with notify.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a few months since you asked, but in case you're still wondering (or anyone else is), you're probably receiving a `nil` because Fitbit does not expose its data over Bluetooth.  There's a discussion stating this on the Fitbit developers forum here: https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Web-API/Where-is-the-Bluetooth-SDK-Can-my-app-communicate-directly-with-the-Fitbit/td-p/324384

If you scroll through the posts, you'll see that Fitbit still does not have plans to expose data over Bluetooth, because they believe it will adversely affect the battery.